# How re rerun only failed test cases on teamCity, using nunit framework

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, nunit, teamcity

I am facing an issue, I want to re run the failed test cases in TeamCity but I am not able to find solution for nunit framwork. Also, is there anything by which I can use [retry(2)] on my test script that will work for any type of failure. Currently it works for only Assertion failure.

It is possible using try and catch but I want it to be generic, should work at framework level.

Thanks.

I am finding silutions like convert nunit to xunit, but this is not possible for organisational level.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/retry.html), the suggested approach is:

> 3. If a test has an unexpected exception, an error result is returned and it is not retried. Only assertion failures can trigger a retry. **To convert an unexpected exception into an assertion failure, see the ThrowsConstraint.**

In your case, if you have the flexibility to reorganize the test methods, you may consider [ThrowsNothing Constraint](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/ThrowsNothingConstraint.html)